# omitting columns from data

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm

The data set has 252 observations and 18 variables. I needed a test sample with every tenth observation and a training sample with the remaining data so I created two separate datasets:

```
id <- seq(1, nrow(fat), by=10)
test  <- fat[id,]
train <-fat[id,]
```

I can do a linear regression using all predictors except `brozek` and `density`:

```
model2 <- lm(siri ~ .-brozek -density, train)
```

I need to do a principal component regression model

```
fatpca<-prcomp(fat[-id,]
```

but this still includes the variables `brozek` and `density`.

How do I exclude these variables to do a PCR model?

Comment: So this is an indexing in R question; moving to SO.

Answer (score 0):

To remove a couple of variables you have a few choices:

```
trainsub <- subset(train,select=-c(brozek,density))
```

or

```
trainsub <- train[!colnames(train) %in% c("brozek","density"))
```

or

```
trainsub <- dplyr::select(train,-c(brozek,density))
```

You can also use a formula interface with `prcomp`, i.e.

```
prcomp(~ . -brozek - density, data=train)
```